# PHP Contact Form not submitting and shows a white screen

Tags: php, html, email

I'm new to PHP and I'm making a contact form for my website. However whenever I fill out and submit the form it leads me to a blank page and I never receive an email. I have tested it when my website is live. My host is infinity free if it matters.

I tried troubleshooting such as making minor modifications to the code (changing a few names, etc.) Nothing worked.

```
<html>
<section id="contact">
  <div class="container-contact">
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h3> Contact Me </h3>
      <p> I will get back to you shortly. </p>
</div>
<div class="row">
      <div class="column">
    <form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contactform.php">
      <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Your first name..." required>
      <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="Your last name..." required>
      <label for="email">Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..." required>
      <label for="message">Message</label>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write your message..." style="height:170px" required></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</section>
</html>

<?php
  $firstname = $_POST['firstname']
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname']
  $user_email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message']

  $email_from = 'myemail@domain.com'

  $email_subject = "New Form Submission from $firstname.\n";

  $email_body = "First Name: $firstname.\n".
                  "Last Name: $lastname.\n".
                    "Email: $user_email.\n".
                      "Message: $message.\n";

  $to = "myemail@domain.com";

  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply To: $user_email \r\n";

  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

  header("Location: contact.html");

?>
```

Τhe HTML file name is contact.html and the PHP file is contactform.php

The form doesn't submit and I don't receive an email. Am I doing something wrong? Do I need to setup something else?

Thanks in advance,

Thomas

Comment: Have you checked the browser console for errors? Have you checked the web server log for errors? Is the mail service setup on the server to send mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you are getting undefined index errors and your environment is not set to display errors. I would add the `name` attribute to the `input` fields that are missing it as a start.

For example the first name field

```
 <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="Your first name..." required>
```

should be

```
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Your first name..." required>
```

In addition you should look at turning errors on or viewing the log file.

Comment: I turned on display errors and added the name like you suggested. The display errors allowed me to find that I missed a few ”;”. Now I no longer get a blank screen but instead it sends me back to the contact page like I specified in the PHP code. But I don’t receive the email. Am I still doing something wrong? My code is the same as before except with ; added were there aren’t and I added the name in the HTML.

Comment: @Thomas I took a look at your hosting provider and it seems they limit what can be done with PHP's mail() function (see https://infinityfree.net/support/php-mail/). My guess is that is why you don't receive the email. If you have a GMail account you can use their instruction for setting that up, the code will not be much different than what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening due to PHP parse error in your page. You need to use semicolon(;) in PHP, in order to end a statement.

Instead of,
`$firstname = $_POST['firstname']`
It should be,
`$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];`